# Rails Route Bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am building custom rails routes for methods that I require. I have created the method as:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
    def mainSearch
        .....etc
    end
```

and testing the route first with:

```
match '/mainSearch/:latitude', to: 'requests#mainSearch', via: 'get' 

running: localhost:3000/mainSearch/40.0
```

worked, but then extending to:

```
match '/mainSearch/:latitude/:longitude', to: 'requests#mainSearch', via: 'get'
running: localhost:3000/mainSearch/40.0/80.0
```

resulted in the error `No route matches [GET] "/mainSearch/40.0/80.0`"

even though in the defined rails routes it clearly notes that the route exists:

[image]

This route should clearly work, but it notes there is no route. How can this be alleviated?

Comment: The route config, and the request url, both look good. Have you restarted the server before trying the new url? It could be something simple like that. :-)

Comment: I have tried that, but still the error. I have created routes so many times, an error now makes absolutely no sense, is there anything else that could be going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, [dynamic segments don't accept dots](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) - this is because the dot is used as a separator for formatted routes. If you need to use a dot within a dynamic segment, add a constraint that overrides this.

Go this way:

```
get '/mainSearch/:latitude/:longitude',
  to: 'requests#mainSearch',
  constraints: { latitude: /\-?\d+\.\d+/, longitude: /\-?\d+\.\d+/ }
```